# wp_redirect not working on plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a worpdress plugin, and I have a big problem, wp_redirect is not working.

this is my code:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in())
{
echo 'loggedin';
}
else
{
echo network_home_url( '/receptionist' );
wp_redirect( network_home_url( '/receptionist' ) );
exit;
}
?>
```

I also try wp_safe_redirect and header to redirect, but no result.
Can some one help me to found the error

Comment: the `echo network_home_url( '/receptionist' );` suggests that headers are send. You should remove it and anything else that forces to send headers before the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with javascript, add this code:

```
window.location= <?php echo "'" . $redirect_url."'"; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
function wp5673fg_redirect()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in())
    {
        echo 'loggedin';
    }
    else
    {
        wp_safe_redirect(network_home_url('/receptionist'));
    }
}
add_action('init', 'wp5673fg_redirect');
```